# How to parse json generated by protobuf library?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark instance that needs to parse some messages from multiple sources.
We have a protobuf schema shared that is used to build the various "clients" implementations and the descriptor.

in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.protobuf.functions.from_protobuf.html#pyspark.sql.protobuf.functions.from_protobuf it's written that pyspark sql offer a way to import a "binary" protobuf source.

In my project however some of the clients doesn't send the "binary" protobuf blobs, but reliese on the protobuf libraries to send data in a "canonical" json. the details of the format are https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#json , but the main differences are related to the "case style" (snake in the .proto file, camel in the json) and in the feature of the `json_name` field option that let us to specify shorten field names in the sent jsons.

I don't find any explicit support for this "format" in pyspark, and trying to use a "generic" json parser isn't really a working solution, as for the inconsitencies related to the "canonical" json.

Is there a way to easily import this kind of format in pyspark?

--- example:

let's say that I have this schema:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package my_package;

message MyMessage {
    string my_field = 1;
    string my_long_name_field = 2 [json_name = "short"];
}
```

using this schema and `buf` I create the clients code and use them to send jsons. One of them could be:

```json
{
    "myField": "myValue",
    "short": "myOtherValue"
}
```

now in pyspark I need to "parse" this payload. My goal here is to be able to understand the json and also to "map the fields" on the original names

so I would need to have a "row" with again `my_field` and `my_long_name_field` as column.

Comment: have you looked at from_json? you can specify the schema when you call it

Comment: but what kind of schema? is from_json also able to "remap back" from shorter `json_name`s and came case names to the original style defined in the .proto files?

I had a look but it seemd not really meant to be used to support this workflow

Comment: pretty much ddl if you use a string [from_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json).  but you can also use a StructType.  This lets you specify all the field name and their types.

Comment: please have a look at the added example: I had a look, but I'm not sure it's possible to use `StructType` to map  `myField` to `my_field` and `short` to `my_long_name_field` in pyspark (basically this is done "for free" with `from_protobuf` and the binary messages